# How can I find client IP on Third-party registration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api, registration, facebook-login

In my app, I allow users to register by LinkedIn and Facebook.
The user push button, that open request to the third-party api (oauth 2.0), and once the authentication completed - the third-party send request to our app with the user details.

Now, can i get the user IP from this request? or the IP on this request is of the third party?

I can cause the user to call our app when pushing the registration button and request authentication from the app later, after getting user IP, but it is less convenient and less natural.

I'm using .net
thanks!

Comment: why do you need their IP address..? do any of the api's have examples of how to get the IP.. ? can you explain why you need the IP addresses

Comment: we use the ip to determine some things like the user place etc.

Comment: I would think that you would use the Location Services for that .. but anyway

Comment: can u give example of location service that dont use ip?
short google "C# get client location" give me results that use ip...

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my localhost, and for my surprise - the client IP of the request that sent from Facebook was my client IP 127.0.0.1